# How to convert Ints to Strings in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have looked into JS and the P5.js references and I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. I'm using p5.js with the DOM and Sound libraries

```
var year = 0 
var yearST

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 750);

}

function draw() {

  background(210)
  textAlign(RIGHT,TOP)
  yearST = str(year)

  textSize(15)
  console.log(yearST) //This is the var that matters
  text(("Years survived: " + yearST), 990, 10)
}
```

The console.log() that logs yearST returns

```
function () { [native code] }
```

Please help, what's the problem with this code. (No changes when adding semicolons, I tried)

This is what it looks like when it is run in a browser:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spCNp.png), That's supposed to be a 0 at the end of the string

Comment: What makes you think there's anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `year` is already a function in the P5.js library. You can find it in the reference [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/year).

So when you call `str(year)` you're really passing in the `year()` function, not your `year` variable.

Just rename your `year` variable to something that doesn't collide with an existing function, or use [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) to prevent P5.js from cluttering the global namespace like this.

Comment: Thank you so much!